# How to use NULL value in NewtonSoft JSON tree?

Tags: c#, null, json.net

I would like to use `null` values in a tree like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
jObject jX = new JObject(
  new JProperty("name" : "Amsterdam"),
  booleanfunction(x) ?
    null
    :
    new JProperty("phone", 1234567890)
);
```

but the `null` seems to cause a runtime exception `Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`

I find this a pity, because I am used to do similar with a tree of XElement, like this:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
XElement Xvar =
  new XElement("div",
    _IsInvoice ? 
      null
      :
      new XElement("p", "sometext")
  );
```

So why is this working just fine with XElement, and not with Newtonsoft, or how do I get this to work with Newtonsoft too?

The question could also be:

How to add an element conditionally in the tree with Linq? Is it possible without the ternary operator (x ? y : z), just with `if` in the middle of the tree?

Comment: because json `{ "name" : "Amsterdam", null }` is no valid ... what may be valid is `{ "name" : "Amsterdam"}` or `{ "name" : "Amsterdam", "phone" : null }`

Comment: So you want to add this property `new JProperty("phone", 1234567890)` if `booleanfunction(x)` evaluates to false ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee What I need is to add a bunch of JProperty elements to the JObject. However, one JProperty should only be included on some condition, e.g. if the value is not null. With XElement this ternary ? operator is very useful, but the same seems not possible with a Json tree.

Comment: you can do this with Linq `new JProperty[] { new JProperty("name" : "Amsterdam"),
  booleanfunction(x) ?
    null
    :
    new JProperty("phone", 1234567890)}.Where(x=>x !=null).ToArray()`

Comment: @Selvin Great solution but it only applies to arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Newtonsoft is different than XElements in this regard. So better avoid the `null` and either insert a dummy property instead, or do not use the ternary ? operation at all.

In both cases, after building that tree, we can use `Remove(string propertyName)` to get rid of the dummy element, or the unwanted element.

If someone has a better solution that builds the correct tree "in one stroke", welcome!

Answer (score 0):

`JObject` does not accept `null` in it's constructor. You can fix this by changing your code to the following:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
jObject jX;
if(booleanfunction(x)) {
    jX = new JObject(new JProperty("name" : "Amsterdam"));
} else {
    jX = new JObject(new JProperty("name" : "Amsterdam"), new JProperty("phone", 1234567890));
}
```

You could also [Add](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Add.htm) the `JProperty` `phone` in the `else` block to the `JObject`.

Comment: Indeed there are other ways to build the tree with or without some element. However, the method with XElement I find very elegant and concise, and avoids duplicate code. And imagine that the tree might have more conditional parts . . .

Answer (score 0):

You may check it inline and determine where the value should be null:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
jObject jX = new JObject(
  new JProperty("name" : "Amsterdam"),
    new JProperty("phone", booleanfunction(x)? "1234567890": null)
);
```

Comment: Nice, but how can I include the entire `phone` property based on some condition?

Comment: @Roland what do you mean by entire phone property?

Comment: What I mean is that the JObject either has the name property, or has both the name and the phone property, depending on the booleanfunction result.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set a Property to null you can use `JValue.CreateNull()`.

For example for this JSON:

```
{ "test": null }
```

You do:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
var jsonObject = new JObject();
jsonObject.Add(new JProperty("test", JValue.CreateNull());
```

Comment: Thanks for your interesting answer. Did you test with the example in my question? I am not in C# development currently, please help me test, so that I can accept your answer. Btw, if you think my question is useful, you may upvote :-)